# Can't remove the element in a mutable set if it is modified in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an issue when using `removeAll()`, some objects can't be removed properly.

```
data class Dog(var name: String)

val dog1 = Dog(name = "dodo")
val dog2 = Dog(name = "mimi")

val set = mutableSetOf<Dog>()
set.add(dog1)
set.add(dog2)

dog1.name = "dodo2"

val beforeSize = set.size // 2

set.removeAll { true }

val afterSize = set.size  // why it is 1!?, I expect it should be 0
```

The `removeAll` didn't work as I expected. There is still one element in the mutable set.  Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Javadoc of `Set`:

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

By writing

```
dog1.name = "dodo2"
```

you did exactly that, you changed the object in a way that affects `equals` comparisons. Specifically, by using the construct

```
set.removeAll { true }
```

you exercised a code path in `LinkedHashSet` that visits each element, tests the predicate on it, and then tries to remove it as if by calling `set.remove(it)`. This will cause `it` to recalculate its hash code, now different from what it was when you inserted it into the set. `LinkedHashSet` will then look up the corresponding hash bucket and fail to find `it` there.

Comment: Isn't the "hash bucket" already updated after the object is mutated? Let's just put a single object in a set then change some variable of that object and check the mutated object's hash code against the item in the set, they have the same hash code. Is what you called "hash bucket" kept separately or I am missing some important point in this context?

Comment: You never compare objects by hash code, you only use it to narrow down where to look for it. When OP's code wants to remove the object, it gets the new hashcode but the object's location is according to the old hashcode.

Comment: Why is it not the case on JDK 14(`kotlinc-jvm 1.4.30 (JRE 14+36-1461)`)? I got `after_size set` to 0 for `JRE 14+36-1461` while 1 for `JRE 1.8.0_292-b10`.

Comment: Same output from `Kotlin version 1.4.30 (JRE 11.0.10+9)`: after_size = 0

Comment: @schemacs Compare the source code of `LinkedHashSet.iterator().remove()` in Java 8 and Java 11, that's where I expect you to find the answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks, I found this fix after debugging for different JDKs [JDK-8170733 HashMap.HashIterator.remove method does not use cached value for the hash code.](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170733).

Comment: @schemacs Excelent, that's exactly the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the object after it has been added to the set. That should be avoided

You can use `clear` instead:

```
set.clear()
```

Or move the mutation of your object:

```
val dog1 = Dog(name = "dodo")
val dog2 = Dog(name = "mimi")

dog1.name = "dodo2"
val set = mutableSetOf(dog1, dog2)
```